# Bootstrap 4: Dropdown menu is going off to the right of the screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to get the drop down items to not go off the page. I tried a couple of things from BS3 but they don't seem to work. I'm not sure if its because of the `ml-auto`.  (ignore the if-else statements)

Here's the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/bbennett36/pen/oByzgw):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #3c763d!important;">

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right navbar-toggler-custom" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#searchNav" aria-controls="searchav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

    </button>

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

    </button>

    <!-- <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button> -->

    <div id="logo">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Company</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="searchNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">

        <form action="/search" class="form-inline">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="keyword" name="keyword" :value='keyword' type="text" placeholder="Search for jobs" />
          <!-- <div class="input-group"> -->

          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="location" name="location" :value='location' type="text" placeholder="Location" />
          <!-- <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Find Jobs</button> -->
          <!-- </span> -->
          <!-- </div> -->

          <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Find Jobs</button>
        </form>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/post" class="nav-link"><strong>Post Job</strong></a></li>

        <div class="hidden-lg-up">

          <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item">
            <a v-if="!user_logged" href="/signup" class="nav-link"><strong>Register</strong></a>
          </li>

          <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" class="nav-item">
            <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/profile" class="nav-link"><strong>Profile</strong></a>
          </li>

          <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" class="nav-item">
            <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/applied" class="nav-link"><strong>My Jobs</strong></a>
          </li>

          <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" class="nav-item">
            <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/searches" class="nav-link"><strong>My Searches</strong></a>
          </li>

          <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'company'" class="nav-item">
            <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'company'" href="/dashboard" class="nav-link"><strong>Employer Dashboard</strong></a>
          </li>

          <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item">
            <a v-if="!user_logged" href="/login" class="nav-link"><strong>Login</strong></a>
          </li>

          <li v-if="user_logged" class="nav-item">
            <a v-if="user_logged" href="/logout" class="nav-link"><strong>Logout</strong></a>
          </li>
        </div>

        <div class="hidden-md-down">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <strong>Account</strong>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

              <!-- <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="!user_logged" href="/signup" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Register</strong></a>
              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/profile" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Profile</strong></a>
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/applied" class="dropdown-item"><strong>My Jobs</strong></a>
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/searches" class="dropdown-item"><strong>My Searches</strong></a>

              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'company'" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'company'" href="/dashboard" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Employer Dashboard</strong></a>
              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="!user_logged" href="/login" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Login</strong></a>
              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="user_logged" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="user_logged" href="/logout" class="dropdown-item">
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <strong>Logout</strong>
              </a>
              <!-- </li> -->
            </div>

          </li>
        </div>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 283, accepted):

Bootstrap has this built in already: See [Menu Alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment). Just add the `dropdown-menu-right` class to the `dropdown-menu` div.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
```

**Working Example:** (open Full Page)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark bg-primary">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <form action="#" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="keyword" name="keyword" :value='keyword' type="text" placeholder="Search for jobs" />
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="location" name="location" :value='location' type="text" placeholder="Location" />
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Find Jobs</button>
    </form>

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
          <strong>Post Job</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <strong>Register</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <strong>Profile</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <strong>My Jobs</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <strong>My Searches</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <strong>Employer Dashboard</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <strong>Login</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <strong>Logout</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <strong>Account</strong>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <strong>Register</strong>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <strong>Profile</strong>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <strong>My Jobs</strong>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <strong>My Searches</strong>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <strong>Employer Dashboard</strong>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <strong>Login</strong>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <strong>Logout</strong>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.4.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, I didnt think calling "dropdown-menu-right" would align the items to the left lol Thanks!

Comment: This worked, but a mistake of putting this same class on all the dropdowns .. so make sure you just this class on the last dropdown - which is going out of the screen.

Comment: UPDATE: Here is the Bootstrap 4's updated menu alignment documentation. The one mentioned in this answer is out of date: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

Comment: @Paula Thanks Paula, updated the answer with the current docs and dependencies.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks, I never thought about this fix

Comment: Just wanted to say for Bootstrap v5: use `dropdown-menu-end`

Comment: this saved me the hair that is left on my head. Silly problem to run into but such a simple fix too :D

Answer (score 29):

In Bootstrap 5 (beta 2) you can use `dropdown-menu-end`:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct. The answer with the green tick is now outdated.

Answer (score 8):

For the benefit of those who stumble upon this issue when googling but are using react, the accepted answer (whilst correct) won't solve the issue for you. React ignores 'dropdown-menu-right' when you add it manually to the className. Instead, update your code to the below and it correctly sets the same class.

For javascript

```
<DropdownMenu right>
```

For typescript

```
<DropdownMenu right={true}>
```

Putting it in here as this thread appeared when I was googling the issue and took me quite a while to figure out the correct solution for bootstrap 4 in react (reactstrap).

Comment: See Docs:https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/ "Alignment" section. (Granted, it took me finding this answer to be able to find the right part in the docs)

Answer (score 6):

In your style sheet, for `.dropdown-menu` change `left: 0;` to `right: 0;`.

Comment: Seems like that should be the solution but its not working

Comment: You have to remove the left attribute or else the above will not work since it is still set to 0. I normally stay well away from using !important as it is bad practice.

Comment: I think its default with BS4 which is why I was using the !important.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking over your code and I think the accepted answer addresses a different problem. If the menu move to the left or the right of the page and is not under the button, it is because you are missing the parent class `.btn-group` and it seems like your `.dropdown-toggle` and `.dropdown-menu` classes are on the wrong elements. Here is the most basic example from the Bootstrap 4 docs.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Right-aligned menu
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I only went over a small block of your code, but at the end where you have a dropdown on large screens, I focused on this.

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <!--- change this line --->
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <strong>Account</strong>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

              <!-- <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="!user_logged" href="/signup" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Register</strong></a>
              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/profile" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Profile</strong></a>
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/applied" class="dropdown-item"><strong>My Jobs</strong></a>
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/searches" class="dropdown-item"><strong>My Searches</strong></a>

              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'company'" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'company'" href="/dashboard" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Employer Dashboard</strong></a>
              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="!user_logged" href="/login" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Login</strong></a>
              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="user_logged" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="user_logged" href="/logout" class="dropdown-item">
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <strong>Logout</strong>
              </a>
              <!-- </li> -->
            </div>

          </li>
```

to

```
 <li class="nav-item btn-group">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <strong>Account</strong>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

              <!-- <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="!user_logged" href="/signup" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Register</strong></a>
              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/profile" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Profile</strong></a>
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/applied" class="dropdown-item"><strong>My Jobs</strong></a>
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" href="/searches" class="dropdown-item"><strong>My Searches</strong></a>

              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'company'" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'company'" href="/dashboard" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Employer Dashboard</strong></a>
              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="!user_logged" href="/login" class="dropdown-item"><strong>Login</strong></a>
              <!-- </li> -->

              <!-- <li v-if="user_logged" class="nav-item"> -->
              <a v-if="user_logged" href="/logout" class="dropdown-item">
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <strong>Logout</strong>
              </a>
              <!-- </li> -->
            </div>

          </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap 4**

For LTR (Left To Right) languages (English, Spanish, ..):
Use the built-in class `dropdown-menu-right` with `dropdown-menu`

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    ...
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">English</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Arabic</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Himyaritic</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

For RTL (Right To Left) languages (Arabic, Hebrew, ..):

1. Create a new class e.g. `dropdown-menu-left`
2. Use it as follows: `<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">`
3. Add the following to your css file:

```css
.dropdown-menu-left {
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 5 you can several options for displaying the dropdown  such as changing the dropdown to dropleft, dropright
You can get better answer from the docs here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/