# Bootstrap 4.0.0 Right aligned navbar dropdown menu goes out of viewport when opened

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

is there a way to fix this problem using Bootstrap 4.0.0?  I would like the right edge of the opened dropdown menu to be aligned with the right side of the dropdown toggle button.  Here is a picture so you can see how it is currently appearing.

[image]

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CS50Net</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">{{ session.username }}</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle to replicate the problem, please.

Comment: @Studocwho I was about to do that for you, but Lahar Shah below answered it, just needed to add a class dropdown-menu-right.  Thanks anyways!

Comment: refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046287/bootstrap-4-dropdown-menu-is-going-off-to-the-right-of-the-screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `.dropdown-menu-right` class to `<div class="dropdown-menu">`

Comment: Sweet, thanks.  Will mark as answer when SO let's me.  Cheers!