# Bootstrap: dynamically generated button has dropdown with form go outside of screen if near window margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My issue is identical to that of [Bootstrap 4.0.0 Right aligned navbar dropdown menu goes out of viewport when opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416054/bootstrap-4-0-0-right-aligned-navbar-dropdown-menu-goes-out-of-viewport-when-ope), however in my case I have a large number of dynamically generated buttons, each with its own dropdown menu, and they wrap around in the navbar, so `.dropdown-menu-right` is not an acceptable solution, because if the last element then wraps and finds itself as the first element of the second row on the left, the dropdown will exit the viewport on the left.

Consider this example (the dropdown menus are the ones labelled "scan", and each dropdown contains a form):

[image]

How can I force these dropdowns to automatically stay inside the view?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CS50Net</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item d-flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">something else here - a very long element</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```