# Bootstrap 5 dropdown-menu cut off to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

The dropdown for User is cuf of, I'm using Bootstrap 5. I read an older article here on stackoverflow that recommended putting `.dropdown-menu-left`/`.dropdown-menu-right` on the `</ul>` which didn't work for me.

I think what would work if I somehow could bring my dropdown to appear to the bottom left of my User link. Blow I attached the source code, probably a little bit to much, but maybe you need to see the entire `nav`.

[image: dropdown cut off]

See dropdown menu cutting of to the right.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">
      <img src="../static/logo.png" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
      Homepage
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="/blog">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false">Username
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 5: Dropdown menu go out off to the right of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214822/bootstrap-5-dropdown-menu-go-out-off-to-the-right-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 8):

**left** and **right** [have changed](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#rtl) to **start** and **end** in Bootstrap 5. Therefore..

`dropdown-menu-right` is now `dropdown-menu-end`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">
      <img src="../static/logo.png" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
      Homepage
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="/blog">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false">Username
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/viwn2SdxCd)